# The following defines a group action of G on the plane R^2. Geometrically describe all the orbits.

Tags: group-theory

$$
\begin{bmatrix}a &  0\\
b−a & b\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}ax\\(b − a)x + by\end{bmatrix}.$$

where a,b are real and non-zero.

Okay so I have Orb(0,0) = {(0,0)} (the origin) and Orb(0,1) = {(0,b):b is non-zero} (the y-axis excluding the origin).

I also have Orb(1,-1) = {(a,-a)} (the line y=-x) and Orb(1,0) =(a,b-a)} but I wasn't sure how to describe this last part geometrically? Do I describe it in terms of quadrants?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please check whether the formatting I did is correct. (And make a note for next time!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orbit of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is what's left after the first three orbits, which you calculated correctly. (Except that you should mention that the orbit of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ does not include the origin.)

That is, the orbit of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ consists of all points with an arbitrary first coordinate $x \ne 0$, and an arbitrary second coordinate $y \ne - x$. (The last condition holding because $b \ne 0$, so that $b - a \ne -a$.)

In other words, the whole plane minus the $y$-axis, and the line $y = - x$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... this is what I had but wasn't sure of the best way to describe it.

Comment: *"All the rest"* seems the best way to me, but I'm not the one whose work has to be graded ;-)

Comment: lol thanks... describing whats happening in words is probably my least favourite bit of maths.